# Asymptotic formula/closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{\log n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, asymptotics, closed-form

I was trying to get an asymptotic formula for the sum
$$\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log n}$$
this looks a bit tricky, but I still tried it. We have

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log n}&=-\sum_{n=2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log(nt)}\Bigg{|}_{t=1}^{t=\infty}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{x}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac1{t\log^2(nt)}dt
\end{align}
Now I don't know what to do further. Any help would be appreciated. Any asymptotic formula or closed form would help.
**Note:** I will probably update this question to post more of my work.
**Update:** I proved that this sum is $O(x/\log x)$, and this was also mentioned in the comments. But I want to improve this. How can one improve the error term?

Comment: Probably big-oh of $x/\log x$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how can you say "probably"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh proved this. But, this is not much good. I want an even better bound.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: You've written $x\log x$, but you mean $x/\log x$, right?

Comment: Oh yes @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^x {\frac{1}{{\log n}}}  \le \frac{1}{{\log 2}} + \sum\limits_{n = 3}^x {\int_{n - 1}^n {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}} }  = \frac{1}{{\log 2}} + \int_2^x {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}} 
$$
and
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^x {\frac{1}{{\log n}}}  \ge \sum\limits_{n = 2}^x {\int_n^{n + 1} {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}} }  \ge \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{x - 1} {\int_n^{n + 1} {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}} }  = \int_2^x {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}} .
$$
Thus, by the known asymptotic expansion of the logarithmic integral,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^x {\frac{1}{{\log n}}}  = \int_2^x {\frac{{dt}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O}(1) \sim \frac{x}{{\log x}}\left( {1 + \frac{{1!}}{{\log x}} + \frac{{2!}}{{\log ^2 x}} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: And $\lim_{x\to \infty} Li(x)-\sum_{n=1}^x 1/\log n= \sum_n O(\frac{1}{n\log^2 n})$ converges

Answer (score 1):

By Riemann-Stieltjes integration we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{2\le n\le x}{1\over\log n}
&=\sum_{2<n\le x}{1\over\log n}+{1\over\log2} \\
&=\int_2^x{\mathrm d(t-\{t\})\over\log t}+{1\over\log2} \\
&=\int_2^x{\mathrm dt\over\log t}+{1\over\log2}-\int_2^x{\mathrm d\{t\}\over\log t} \\
&=\operatorname{Li}(x)+{1\over\log2}-{\{x\}\over\log x}-\int_2^x{\{t\}\over t\log^2t}\mathrm dt \\
&=\operatorname{Li}(x)+A+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log x\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

in which

$$
A={1\over\log2}-\int_2^\infty{\{t\}\over t\log^2t}\mathrm dt
$$

and $\operatorname{Li}(x)=\operatorname{li}(x)-\operatorname{li}(2)$ is the logarithmic integral function satisfying

$$
\operatorname{Li}(x)\sim{x\over\log x}
$$